# Convert Web page to ARFF File for Weka classification

Tags: classification, weka, arff, text-classification

I want to classify 10 webpages using weka.
How to convert web pages in to Weka's ARFF file format?
Do i need to convert all the 10 page in to one ARFF file or 
Do i need to convert  ARFF files for each web page i.e 10 ARFF files.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what sort of information you want to extract from the webpages. The whole text? A list of numbers on that page? Etc. If you want to compare information from each page to each other, you would probably unify them in one ARFF file.

Comment: I want to classify web pages based bag of words model using a classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep your HTML formatting, this is relatively easy. Just put your HTML files in separate folders/directories (each directory a class), then apply the `TextDirectoryLoader` converter, as explained in the [Text categorization with WEKA](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA) tutorial.

Assuming that e.g. you have two classes, what you should do (and get with this procedure) is a single ARFF file with one instance per file, and the text of each file into a single field (attribute value) for a text attribute, along with the class (directory name). Then you can follow up with the StringToWordVector filter to transform documents into term vectors and perform classification.

Comment: @Jose Maria Gomez Hidalg How we can generate arff file for Reuters Dataset which is in XML format?

Comment: If you mean a single file with all the articles in XML format (that was the original format for the collection, I used so in my Thesis), you have to code a translator that, for instance, keeps only the text of each article and adds it to the directories corresponding to its categories.

Comment: I guess this is a different question, Please open a new post for the same in the benefit of community.